# meaning of "tag types" in HTML

Tags: html, terminology

[From a tutorial](https://youtu.be/RvCbTYJqepU?t=206)

> it turns out that
> there are many allowable **tag types** in
> HTML and many allowable attributes which
> sometimes depend on those **tag types**

I understand [what an HTML tag is](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_html.asp). For instance, this snippet has 2 [`<a>` tags](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp).

```
<html>
  <body>
    <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>
    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">Visit stackoverflow!</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

I also understand [type attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_type.asp).

I don't understand what does "tag types" mean. I googled it but the results are about type attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He said: "It turns out that there are many allowable tag types in HTML", what he means is that there are many types of tags.

Types of tags would be `<a>`, `<abbr>`, etc.

Comment: Thank you.  [<a>](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) is an HTML tag, right?

Comment: At the same time, `<a>` is also a types of tag. Which means "a HTML tag" and "a types of tag" are the same thing.  Is my understanding correct?

Comment: You can understand this by: "There are many fruits: oranges, apples, bananas..." and "There are many types of fruits: oranges, apples, bananas...". Got it? Now replace "fruit" for "HTML tag" –  What he means is that there are many types of HTML tags, as there as many types of fruits in the example.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. Generally, apples are a type of fruits, which could be considered a class. Suppose there are 3 apples on the table, which are 3 instances of class apple. I just added a snippet which contains two `<a>` tags and both of them are a type of <a> tag. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Not actually... You don't really have "a type of a tag", you have "a tag". Once you add two `<a>` tags, both of them are `<a>` tags, not "types of `<a>` tags". The only thing he tried to explain with "there are many types of HTML tags" is that "there are many HTML tags".